# WPF Telerik RadGridView Filter not being applied for Checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, filter, telerik

I have a page with a `RadGridView` and some buttons for quickly filtering the `RadGridView` data.

When a user clicks one of the buttons, a `FilterDescriptor` is added to the view and the filter is applied.  If a user clicks "Show New Items only", a filter is applied and new items will be shown.

This is working for all but my boolean checkbox columns.  When the filter is applied, no matching items are found.  I've tried a number of things, but nothing seems to work.

## XAML

```
<telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn UniqueName="CorrectiveActionRequired" Header="Corrective Action" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True" IsFilterable="True"
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding CorrectiveActionTaken, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                            AutoSelectOnEdit="True" EditTriggers="CellClick" />
```

## C#

```
private void FilterByCorrectiveActionRequired(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.NearMissRadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Clear();
    FilterDescriptor descriptor = new FilterDescriptor();
    descriptor.Member = "CorrectiveActionRequired";
    descriptor.Operator = FilterOperator.IsEqualTo;
    descriptor.Value = true;
    this.NearMissRadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Add(descriptor);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Member` property to "CorrectiveActionTaken" which is the actual name of property (I suppose):

```
private void FilterByCorrectiveActionRequired(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.NearMissRadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Clear();
    FilterDescriptor descriptor = new FilterDescriptor();
    descriptor.Member = "CorrectiveActionTaken"; //<--
    descriptor.Operator = FilterOperator.IsEqualTo;
    descriptor.Value = true;
    this.NearMissRadGridView.FilterDescriptors.Add(descriptor);
}
```

Comment: That worked.  I assumed the Member needed to match the UniqueName, not the property name.  Thank you!